# SMD component identification: ADI "8 8A"

Tags: pcb, analog, identification, components

I'm having trouble identifying this ADI part on this board I'm working on. I'm assuming it's ADI from the logo on the left, and the text on the right just says "8 8A". I've had no luck finding this IC from the ADI package marking database and general searching. Would anyone be able to help me out?

[image: Unknown ADI IC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably this part [AD8512](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8510_8512_8513.pdf) JFET opamp.